# Add a word at the beginning of the line in a text file

Tags: shell, search, solaris

Search for the group of lines starting with "zone" and add a word "Heading" at the beginning of the previous line. Thanks for your help in advance

Code:

```
    Zoning A
     zone zonename1
     zone zonename2
     zone zonename3

   Team B
     zone zonename4
     zone zonename5
```

Desired output:

```
     Heading Zoning A
       zone zonename1
       zone zonename2
       zone zonename3

     Heading Team B
        zone zonename4
        zone zonename5
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service, show us the code that you have tried and where it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk. As long as the group heading doesn't start with word *zone*:

```
$ awk '
/^ *zone/&&p!~/^ *zone/ {
    sub(/^ */,"&Heading ",p)
}
NR>1 { print p }
{ p=$0 }
END { print p }
' file
    Heading Zoning A
     zone zonename1
     zone zonename2
     zone zonename3

   Heading Team B
     zone zonename4
     zone zonename5
```

Comment: Great! Worked. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you could use `perl`:

```
perl -000 -pe 's/^/Heading/;s/\s+/ /' inputfile
Heading Zoning A
     zone zonename1
     zone zonename2
     zone zonename3

Heading Team B
     zone zonename4
     zone zonename5
```